# Getting 6.33 from an equation in Javascript when it should output 8.99

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some simple math in Javascript, but my equation's result is drastically different than what it should be. The math is:

```
3.05+(((0.32*0)+3.28)+(1+(0.19*0))*(2.66*1^2))*1;
```

When I did it out by hand, and then used Wolfram Alpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/) I get the correct result of 8.99. However, when I use the equation in Javascript I mysteriously get 6.33

The actual equation looks like

```
VO2move = VO2rest+(((C1*g2)+VO2walkmin)+(1+(C2*g2))*(C3*s2^2))*t2;
```

but I removed all the variables in an attempt to debug (I thought it might be some error where I needed parseInt)

Here are the whole functions for reference

```
function calc(){
    var temp = 0;
    var total = 0;

    for(i = 0; i<sArr.length; i++){
        total = total + calc2(i);
    }

    var o = document.getElementById("output");
    o.value = total;
}

function calc2(i){
    var s = document.getElementById("s"+i);
    var g = document.getElementById("g"+i);
    var t = document.getElementById("t"+i);
    var VO2walkmin = 3.28; 
    var VO2rest = 3.05; 
    var C1 = 0.32;
    var C2 = 0.19;
    var C3 = 2.66;
    var Cdecline = 0.73;
    var s2 = s.value;
    var g2 = g.value;
    var t2 = t.value;
    var negGrade = g.value;

    if(g2 < 0){g2 = 0};

    //VO2move = ((C1 * g2)+VO2walkmin)+((1+(C2*g2))*(C3*s2^2)); //ORIGINAL TRANSCRIPTION

    //VO2move = VO2rest+(((C1*g2)+VO2walkmin)+(1+(C2*g2))*(C3*s2^2))*t2; // TRANSLATED FROM COPY PASTE  
    VO2move = 3.05+(((0.32*0)+3.28)+(1+(0.19*0))*(2.66*1^2))*1; // COPY - PASTED FROM EXCEL

    return VO2move;
}
```

Even naked numbers I still get the output of 6.33. I'm totally puzzled, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: `1^2` what do you think that is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to take the [power (exponentiation) operator `**`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation) instead of the [bitwise XOR operator `^`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_XOR)).

```js
console.log(3.05+(((0.32*0)+3.28)+(1+(0.19*0))*(2.66*1**2))*1);
```